# Angular Input will not be recognized

Tags: angular, typescript, input, webstorm

I am trying, within WebStorm, to implement `@Input-Dekorator`.

Actually it is simple, but my IDE does not suggest my `@Input-variable`.

Code:

"AppComponent" sends to "UserComponent" some value

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {UserComponent} from "./user/user.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent {

    public master_chef:string = "MASTER CHEF";
    constructor () {
        console.log ("App Component");
    }

}
```

and app.component.html

```
<nav>NAVIGATION</nav>
<main>
    <h1>MAIN</h1>
    <user_component> 
       <!--user_component will be recognized, cause i can create user-
         templates, which i see.-->
<!--Usually WebStorm suggest me @Input-Parameter "master_name" and parent-variable "master_chef", but now i can not retrieve these.-->
       [master_name]='master_chef';
    </user_component>
</main>
```

UserComponent looks like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user_component',
    template: `<h3>HELLO FROM USER</h3>`
})

export class UserComponent {

    @Input()
    master_name:string; //this variable will not be suggested above by AppComponent
    constructor () {
        console.log ("User Component");
    }
}
```

I can see only `<h3>HELLO FROM USER</h3>` from my `UserComponent`. What's wrong here?

**UPDATE**

app.component.html looks like this:

```
<nav>NAVIGATION</nav>
<main>
    <h1>MAIN</h1>
    <user_component>
       [master_name]="master_chef";
    </user_component>
</main>
```

Usually WebStorm suggests me input-field master_name from user_component.
But now it will not be recognized or suggested. Event `master_chef` field from `app_component` will not be recognized or suggested.

What's wrong here?

**UPDATE 2**

I've changed the selector name within my component from user_component to user.
One-way from Datasource to View-Target on this way works within app.component.html:
I can see value from detail_message-variable, but [mastername] does not work :(

```
<user>
        [mastername]="masterchef";
        {{detail_message}}

    </user>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webstorm correctly suggests but you should place binding in the tag header, not in the tag body. Also it's not a typescript statement and you don't need to write `;` at the end. In the template you can use only expressions.

```
<nav>NAVIGATION</nav>

<main>
    <h1>MAIN</h1>
    <user_component
       <!--user_component will be recognized, cause i can create user-
         templates, which i see.-->
<!--Usually WebStorm suggest me @Input-Parameter "master_name" and parent-variable "master_chef", but now i can not retrieve these.-->
       [master_name]='master_chef'>
    </user_component>
</main>
```

Comment: @Sam This was a hint to Roman C that his answer required some explanation. We expect this from answers, as explained in [answer].

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Indeed some explanation is planned.

Comment: primitive values not the same as primitive types, you can bind only variable, otherwise it doesn't work, see my previous answer.

Comment: @RomaKap you have errors in the template, webstorm can't determine which component is a binding for.

Comment: I can't see any errors in IDE or in the console from chrome. Thats confusing me. I've simply created second .ts file and second .html file for detail-view of some content. "<user_component>"-tag will be recognized. 
When i'am looking on .ts file, i see, that @master_name will not be used, although, i use at: [master_name] = "master_chef". Thats strange..

Comment: The software development is not easy process, some things you have work with confusing and you have a lot of time spent to understand the concepts. The most useful resource to learn is on the [official web site](https://angular.io/). If you have difficulties to understand the developer documentation, then a lot of tutorials and other resources available on the net.